# Regex for matching string Python

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to match the numeric values of a string:

```
1,000 metric tonnes per contract month
Five cents ($0.05) per tonne
Five cents ($0.05) per tonne
1,000 metric tonnes per contract month
```

My current approach:

```
size = re.findall(r'(\d+(,?\d*).*?)', my_string)
```

What I get with my approach:

```
print size
[(u'1,000', u',000')]
```

As you can see, the number `1` was being cut out from the second element of  the list, why is that? Also, could I get a hint as to how I can match the `$0.05` terms?

Comment: I've edited my code to include '$' as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>>  strs = """1,000 metric tonnes per contract month
Five cents ($0.05) per tonne
Five cents ($0.05) per tonne
1,000 metric tonnes per contract month"""
>>> [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'\$?\d+([,.]\d+)?', strs)]
['1,000', '$0.05', '$0.05', '1,000']
```

Demo : http://rubular.com/r/UomzIY3SD3

Comment: This also matches `1,00000` and doesn't match `1,000.05`.

Answer (score 3):

`re,findall()` returns a tuple of all the capturing groups for each match, and each set of normal parentheses generates one such group. Write your regex like this:

```
size = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?', my_string)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\d{1,3}      # One to three digits
(?:,\d{3})*  # Optional thousands groups
(?:\.\d+)?   # Optional decimal part
```

This assumes that all numbers have commas as thousands separators, i. e. no numbers like `1000000`. If you need to match those too, use

```
size = re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?', my_string)
```

Comment: This fails on simple numbers such as `'1000'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\$?\d+(?:[,.]?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)).*?
```

#### [Live demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/jiq70NEbRp)

Comment: Have a look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you grouping your regex? Try this `r'\$?\d+,?\d*\.?\d*'`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this regex:

r'[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*(?:.[0-9]*)?'

Add \$? at the beginning to optionally catch the $